# How can I get the values from an object that's clicked inside a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vue.js, axios

When a user clicks an item in the below form, I want to call `@click.prevent="Addcart()"`

When `Addcart` is called, inside that method, I want to get the details from the clicked item (ie `result`) and use those values in an ajax call.

Currently, inside `Addcart`, when I run `console.log(this.product_id);`, I get `undefined` in the console.

```
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 mb-5"
            v-for="(result, index) in results"
            :key="result.id">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <input type="text" v-model="result.product_id" />
                    <input type="text" v-model="result.product_price" />
                    <input type="text" v-model="result.product_color" />
                    <input type="text" v-model="result.product_size" />
                    <input type="text" v-model="cart_quantity" />
                    <button @click.prevent="Addcart()" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

> here is javascript code

```
 import axios from "axios";

 export default {
    name: "products",
    components: {},
    data() {
      return {
        cart_quantity: 1,
        results: [],

      };
    },
    created() {
      this.getProducts();
    },
    methods: {
      getProducts() {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost/vue/src/Api/api?action=getproducts")
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.user_Data);
            this.results = res.data.user_Data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      },
      Addcart() {
        let data = new FormData();
        console.log(this.product_id);
        data.append("product_id", this.product_id);
        data.append("cart_price", this.product_price);
        data.append("product_color", this.product_color);
        data.append("product_size", this.product_size);
        data.append("product_qty", this.cart_quantity);
        axios.post('http://localhost/vue/src/Api/api?action=addcart', data).then((res) => {
          if (res.data.error) {
            alert("Error");
          } else {
            alert(res.data.message);
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })


      },
    },
  };
```

Comment: Please show the output of `console.log(res);`

Comment: @WesleySmith this console showing the else statement which i defined in php script when error occured.

Comment: Is `this.results` is being set correctly, and the issue is in `Addcart()`?

Comment: If `console.log(res);` shows an error message from your php script, you'll need to show us that php code as the issue seems to be there

Comment: @WesleySmith yes the issue is in Addcart() function. this.results is working fine and i am getting the results from database in results array

Comment: @WesleySmith Undefined index: product_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\vue\src\Api\api.php but i already set the variables by POST method. the problem is data is not passing to php script from vuejs file

Comment: Looks like you're using variables that don't exist in your axios FormData... i.e. this.product_size

Comment: @JoshBonnick yes I am also thinking about this but can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: The answer below sends the variable `result` to the addCart function, you can use that to send data from inside you result to the axios function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the context of the `addCart` method points to the vue component, *not* the item you're adding as the code seems to expect. To work with the item that was clicked, you'll need to pass the item from the loop in the form to the method as a parameter.

Change your form to:

```
<button @click.prevent="addCart(result)" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</button>
```

Then, change your `addCart` method to:

```
  addCart(item) {
    console.log(item);
    data.append("product_id", item.product_id);
    // ...
  },
```

Note, I made `addCart` start with a lowercase letter out of personal preference and to keep it consistent with your `getProducts`.